# Is Jit Compiler aware of NUMA architecture?

Tags: java, jit, numa

Currently, I've been testing my high-performance computing parallel algorithm on a Windows Google Compute Engine VM. However, the Google VMs (and probably most VMs) do NOT correctly provide the "true" NUMA architecture of the physical host. (For example, if the physical host has 2 CPU sockets, 8 CPU cores/socket, and 2 hyperthreads per CPU core, the VM would simply and incorrectly report -- based on my detective work -- that there are 32 CPU cores from a single socket....it would also report "weird" results for each CPU core's L1/L2 cache because it would "double count" etc.)

In any event, the key question is: does the JIT compiler make use of all this NUMA architecture info, particularly when using the jdk8 parallel stream futures, such as "collectors"? (For example, it would make more sense to attempt to do the "combining" step in the the collectors protocol first for threads that are "close" to each other on the chip before proceeding to the threads that are living "far" (eg on different CPU sockets) away from each other.  (Also, based on the true L2 cache size etc, it would make more sense to pull data in a certain way based on the true L2 cache sizes etc.) I'm assuming that's the main advantage of JIT vs a statically compiled language such as C++, and if I'm right, then when we test our code on "non VM" computers, our Java program will perform even better....(That said, it could be that such optimizations make less than 1% difference, but I would think that for high performance computing, minimizing data transfer accross sockets and making good use of caches makes a decent difference.)

Comment: (I noticed that the GC can be NUMA aware, at least on linux systems, but that doesn't answer whether all aspects of the program would also take the NUMA archictecture into account as well. Also, I don't think GC can be NUMA aware on Windows machines for some reason...)